# Building PJSIP: "Make dep" command giving error on Windows7

Tags: android, makefile, pjsip

I have followed all the steps written in [the pjsip-startup guide](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android).

But the last step (`make dep && make clean && make`) is giving me the following errors. I am on Windows 7.

```
$ make dep && make clean && make
for dir in pjlib/build pjlib-util/build pjnath/build third_party/build pjmedia/b                                                                                                                uild pjsip/build pjsip-apps/build ; do \
        if make  -C $dir dep; then \
            true; \
        else \
            exit 1; \
        fi; \
done
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/android/pjproject-2.2.1/pjlib/build'
make -f /cygdrive/d/android/pjproject-2.2.1/build/rules.mak APP=PJLIB app=pjlib                                                                                                                 depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/android/pjproject-2.2.1/pjlib/build'
.pjlib-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi.depend:1: *** multiple target patterns.  St                                                                                                                op.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/android/pjproject-2.2.1/pjlib/build'
Makefile:88: recipe for target 'depend' failed
make[1]: *** [depend] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/android/pjproject-2.2.1/pjlib/build'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'dep' failed
make: *** [dep] Error 1
```

Can someone help me to resolve these errors? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some research I come to know that don't use WINDOWS for building the PJSIP v2.x version. Now I am going to install Ubuntu  on my system.

The build system is known to work on the following hosts:

- Linux, many types of distributions.
- MacOS X 10.2 mingw (Win2K, XP)
- FreeBSD (must use gmake instead of make)

Building **Win32 applications with Cygwin is currently not supported** by the autoconf script (there are some conflicts with Windows headers), but one can still use the old configure script by calling ./configure-legacy. More over, cross-compilations might also work with Cygwin using this build system.

See the [link](http://www.pjsip.org/using.htm#gnu_req) for details.

Comment: Definitly use linux, on windows is real pain.
We managed to build the android project by carefully following these instructions. Best of luck.

Comment: @Sasha i have installed ubuntu on vmware. ./configure-android works but make dep giving error